# Laravel 4 routes hitting public folder instead of views folder

Tags: php, apache, laravel, laravel-4

I'm a newbie in PHP / Laravel and this might be silly but I can't get this to work. I have these two routes defined in my `routes.php` file:

```
Route::get('about', function()
{
    return 'this is about';
});

Route::get('/', array('as'=>'home', function()
{
    return View::make('hello');
}));
```

If I access my app like: *http://testapp.dev:88* it renders the view correctly. However I get a 404 if I access my app like *http://testapp.dev:88/home* or *http://testapp.dev:88/about*

I checked the apache logs and found these errors:

> [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist:
>   C:/tmp/Git_Repository/website/testapp/public/about
>
> [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist:
>   C:/tmp/Git_Repository/website/testapp/public/home

**Any ideas of why this is happening?**

Note: I'm using Wamp and have the following apache 2.2.22 configuration

```
<Directory "C:/tmp/Git_Repository/website/">
    AllowOverride All
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:88>
    DocumentRoot "C:\tmp\Git_Repository\website\testapp\public"
    ServerName testapp.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you have the Laravel `.htaccess` file in your `public` directory?

Comment: Looks like the `.htaccess`-file in your `/public` directory is missing or the rewrite rules are not working. Make sure you have the `.htaccess` file: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/.htaccess and `mod_rewrite` installed / enabled. And by the way: The name of the route (as in `['as' => 'home' ...]` does not make `/home` an accessible URI, it's just for better referencing within your application, e.g. with `URL::route('home')`. So you can reference the name, no matter what the actual route looks like.

Comment: you have not define home route and if you can't access about route which is defined then there must be problem with your public directory config. Default access i guess is http://localhost/public/about

Comment: .htaccess file is in my public directory but the rewrite module was disabled.  Quasdunk, your comment made me realized this, so if you want add a answer and I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments / answers.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a `home` route declared ib your `routes.php` file, anyways, you may try this:

```
<VirtualHost testapp.dev>
    DocumentRoot "C:\tmp\Git_Repository\website\testapp\public"
    ServerName testapp.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

Also make sure you have added an entry in your `windows/system32/drivers/etc/host` file. like:

```
# The ip address could be something like: 127.0.0.10
127.0.0.10 testapp.dev
```

Then restart the `Apache` and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Working with Apache, if Laravel (or any other application) seems to be mapping the URL to a directory structuer instead of a defined route, the reason is most likely a missing or inactive rewrite rule.

First make sure you have the `.htaccess` chilling in your public directory, looking something [like this](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/.htaccess):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

It's wrapped in an if-statement and will only apply if the Apache-module `mod_rewrite` is loaded. To make sure it is loaded,

**on Windows:**

Open the `httpd.conf`-file (located somewehere in you Apache install folder) in your favourite text editor and look for the line

```
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Make sure to uncomment it by removing the `#` at the beginning

**On Linux (and probably Mac)**

Just run

```
$ a2enmod rewrite
```

Make sure to restart Apache after that, and you should be good to go.

Since version 5.4, PHP ships with a basic built in webserver. It's not as powerful as Apache and is not capable of rewriting URLs, but it's still possible to achieve this behaviour. That's what Laravel's [server.php](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/server.php) is for. So if you don't need the whole power of Apache for your development envirnoment, you could use PHP's built in server in Laravel's root directory (not public) and pass it the router-file:

```
$ php -S localhost:8000 server.php
```

Now you don't have to worry about Apache and rewrite modules, it just works out of the box.